# How not let user go back to login.php without logging out?

Tags: php, logout

I have a login.php, loginer.php, registration.php, register.php, logout.php, logouter.php, dashboard.php and menu.php file as well. The menu.html is included into my dashboard.php because the menu.html contains the button which I have to click on if I would like log out.

I have the folder of the project of mine in htdocs. Inside the project's folder I have a 'hu' folder because the website is in hungarian language at the moment. Inside this 'hu' folder I have all the mentioned .php files apart from dashboard.php and menu.html because these 2 files are in the 'registered' folder which is also inside the 'hu' folder.

I have a registration-login system. But when I log in I do not need to sign out forward to get to login.php because I just have to click on the "back" button.
Why is it happening?

I have already tried to write "session_destroy();" to almost everywhere. I did not work.

This is how login.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Bejelentkezés | LASOW Projekt</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        include 'navbar.html';
    ?>
    <div class="main">
        <h1>Bejelentkezés</h1>
        <form action="loginer.php" method="POST">   
            <label for="">Email:</label><br>
            <input type="text" name="emailaddress"><br>
            <label for="Jelszó:">Jelszó:</label><br>
            <input type="password" name="password"><br>
            <input name="login" type="submit" value="Belépek">
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is how loginer.php looks like:

```
<?php
session_start();
include '../connect.php';

$error = ""; //Variable for storing our errors.
if(isset($_POST["login"]))
{
if(empty($_POST["emailaddress"]) || empty($_POST["password"]))
{
    $error = "Mindkét mező kitöltése kötelező!";
}else
{
    // Define $username and $password
    $emailaddress=$_POST['emailaddress'];
    $password=$_POST['password'];

    // To protect from MySQL injection
    $emailaddress = stripslashes($emailaddress);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $emailaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $emailaddress);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $password);
    $password = md5($password);

    //Check username and password from database
    $sql="SELECT id,emailaddress,password FROM users WHERE emailaddress='$emailaddress' and password='$password'";
    $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    //$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    //email és jelszó létezése esetén folytatódik a folyamat
    //Otherwise echo error.

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1)
    {
    $_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $emailaddress; // Initializing Session
    header("location: registered/dashboard.php"); // átirányítás a login.php-re
    }else
    {
    $error = "Helytelen email vagy jelszó";
    }
}
}
?>
```

This is how register.php looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["register"])){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "lasowcompany";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

mysqli_set_charset($conn,"utf8");
//nem $POST hanem $_POST a htmlspecialchars nem enged javasrcipt kódot be írni az adatbázisba
$surname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['surname']);
$firstname = htmlspecialchars($_POST['firstname']);
$emailaddress = htmlspecialchars($_POST['emailaddress']);
$phonenumber = htmlspecialchars($_POST['phonenumber']);
$password = md5($_POST['password']);
$passwordconfirm = md5($_POST['passwordconfirm']);


if(empty($surname))
    {
        echo "A vezetéknevet meg kell adnod!";
    }
elseif(empty($firstname))
    {
        echo "A keresztnevet meg kell adnod";
    }
elseif(empty($emailaddress))
    {
        echo "Az email címet meg kell adnod";
    }
elseif($password != $passwordconfirm)
    {
        echo "A megadott jelszavak nem egyeznek";
    }
elseif(strlen($password) < 6)
    {
        echo "Minimum 6 karakteres lehet a jelszó";
    }

elseif(empty($password))
    {
        echo "A kívánt jelszót meg kell adnod";
    }else{

    $sql = "INSERT
            INTO 
            users
            (surname, 
            firstname,
            emailaddress,
            phonenumber,
            password)
            VALUES
            ('".$surname."',
             '".$firstname."',
             '".$emailaddress."',
             '".$phonenumber."',
            '".$password."')";

    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
        $conn->close();
        header('Location: dashboard.php');
    }

}
/*$sql = "INSERT INTO users (surname, firstname, emailaddress, phonenumber, password, passwordconfirm)
VALUES ('".$_POST["surname"]."','".$_POST["firstname"]."','".$_POST["emailaddress"]."','".$_POST["phonenumber"]."','".$_POST["password"]."','".$_POST["passwordconfirm"]."')";
*/



?>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php:

```
<?php
 session_start();
 unset($_SESSION['emailaddress']);
 header("Location: logouter.php");
?>
```

dashboard.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    h2 { text-align: center; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['emailaddress'])){
        include 'menu.html';
    }else{
        header("Location: ../logout.php");
        exit();
    }
    ?>
    <h2>Üdv a LASOW rendszerében</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

menu.html:

```
<ul>
        <li><span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span></li>
        <li><a class="active" href="#home">Főoldal</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="dashboard.php">Főoldal</a>
        <a href="../lectures.php">Tudás</a>
        <a href="profile.php">Profil</a>
        <a href="../logout.php">Kilépés</a>
    </div>
    <script>
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "30%";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
</script>
```

Do not let user to go back to login.php if user did not log out.

Comment: in your login page have a condition that check if the user is loggedin then if they loggedin redirect to dashboard or show the login form

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile And how could I make that!

Answer (score -1):

you have to use the **sessions** in every pages that you want to be tracked

Comment: Like on dashboard.php as well?

Comment: which file do you include the most in your files @Erik?

Comment: on the first page you have to start the session then if there's a kind of layering in your site you have to check it, lets say home page where you have to login then you can't go to buy product for example until you login in, so start the session in the home page then in the buy product check if it's already set